# Boolean Expression simplification with steps

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I need to simplify this expression.
($A.B$)'.$B$ + $B'$.$(A' + B')'$

I started of with De Morgan's Law and double Negation

($A'$+ $B'$).$B$ + $B'$.($A$+$B$)

Then I did the distributive laws twice

$A'B$ + $B'B$ + $B'A$ +$B'B$

Then I did Complements Law

$A'B$ + $0$ + $B'A$ + $0$

The answer is apparently $A'B$ but I cannot simplify anymore and I don't know what I did wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't apply De Morgan's Law properly, it should be
$$(A'+B')'\equiv A\cdot B$$
insted of $(A'+B')'\equiv A+B$, which is not correct. If we do everything correctly, should get

\begin{align}
&(A\cdot B)'\cdot B+B'\cdot(A'+B')'\\
\equiv&(A'+B')\cdot B+(B'\cdot A\cdot B)\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
\equiv&A'\cdot B+B'\cdot B+(B'\cdot A\cdot B)\tag*{Distributive law}\\
&\vdots\\
\equiv&A'\cdot B\\
\end{align}
see if you can fill the blank.